# non-suported ERC20 token sent to Ledger Nano X. ANY suggestions as how to get it back?

Tags: transactions

I sent non-supported ERC20 token (Barnbridge BOND)to my Ledger Nano X. The transaction shows on Etherscan.io but of course not on Ledger live or Nano X? Heeeeelp plz.

Comment: You can use a wallet that has support for both ledger and arbitrary tokens, like Metamask, MyEtherWallet, MyCrypto, just to name a few well known wallets.

Comment: by "sent ERC20 token to my Ledger Nano X" do you mean an Ether wallet on your Ledger Nano X?